# Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem: trouble understanding particular part of proof.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I need a certain part of the proof of Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem explained to me. See  http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/Cardinality.pdf at page 233. Please clarify the part just after figure 13.5, concerning the the area of the shaded region. In the second occurence, which part is (A−g(B)) and which part is(g◦ f )(A−g(B))? I can understand that the shaded area is A-g(B) for the first occurence but thereafter I am confused.  I basically need this part of the proof explained to me.

Comment: $g\circ f( A-g(B))$ is the little shaded area inside the big one

Comment: It is suppose to actually represent a smaller area? Can you explain the process a little?  If we are suppose to be simply adding the areas, why would they change just because we apply g◦ f, which are injective functions.

Comment: I think you shouldn't worry too much about the figure, rather you should concentrate on the proof itself, try understanding it and maybe when you do you'll understand what the figure means (I hardly think the figure helps the understanding, and so I don't quite understand why they put it there)

Comment: You might be right, but when you get to the formal proof in that book, you can't make sense of how we came up with the subset G, to partition set A, and create a piecewise function that we can prove to be bijective.  By the way, do you know of any helpful material on proofs of the theorem?

Comment: I could give you two proofs if you want, but I don't know of any book with the proof in it (there must be some, but not in the ones I have). One of the proofs I know is, I suspect, similar to the one you have (I haven't read the one you have, but the figure seems to indicate that), and the other one seems more intuitive to me